# Find all rows with with values from list and which all have the same id MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with conversation ids which is a one-to-many relationship to another table that has conversation users. The conversation users table has the id for the conversation, a unique id and a userID. I can use this:

```
SELECT c_id FROM conversations INNER JOIN conversation_users on conversation_users.cu_convo_id = conversations.c_id
```

which gives me all the rows but I need to find a way to do something like an IN statement because I need to find the conversation id given two user IDs.

Any ideas? Am I approaching this the wrong way completely?

**WORKING ANSWER:**
IN case anyone needs it, the following worked for me:

```
SELECT cu_convo_id FROM conversations 
INNER JOIN conversation_users on 
conversation_users.cu_convo_id = conversations.c_id 
WHERE cu_user_id IN (31,42) 
GROUP BY cu_convo_id
HAVING count(distinct cu_user_id) = 2;
```

if I have 5 IDs to find, i put them on line 4 and then put the number 5 on line 6

Comment: So add a `where` clause at the end with the `in()`. The SQL specs will show you that using `join` does not preclude using `where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a WHERE to your SQL:

```
SELECT c_id FROM conversations 
INNER JOIN conversation_users on 
conversation_users.cu_convo_id = conversations.c_id 
WHERE conversations.usedID IN (1,2);
```

Comment: wow that was way too obvious... I should have realized that. Thanks